# How to write a by making aggregation and flag?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table which has the columns `purchase_id`, `product_group` and `flag` in MySQL. Whenever a purchase is made, a `purchase_id` is created and the purchase can be in any product group and it can be either success or failure and hence the `flag` 'Y' or 'N'.

I have to find the number of failed purchases on each `product_group` and the formula for it is

```
failed_count = total_purchase - failed_flag
```

*i.e.*

```
count_failure = count(purchase_id) - count(flag) where flag = 'N'
```

Here I have to group by `product_group` and find the answer:

```
purchase_id | product_group | flag
------------+---------------+-----
1           | A             | Y
2           | A             | Y
4           | B             | N
7           | B             | N
11          | C             | Y
34          | D             | N
```

When I try to do the calculation based on the group, i get an error as subquery returns more than 1 row.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a basic aggregation query:

```
select product_group, sum(flag <> 'N') as num_failed
from t
group by product_group;
```

If `flag` can be `NULL` use `sum(not flag <=> 'N')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_group, count(*)
  from t
   where flag = 'N'
   group by product_group
```